# How can I pass a prop to my home route after redirecting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router-dom` and would like to pass `:id` to my first route (`/`) when redirecting. The reason for wanting to do this is so that I can access `:id` in my `Interface` component and keep my SPA url consistent. Is it possible to do this?

**Routing**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router>
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <div style={styles.pageContainer}>
            <div style={styles.bodyContainer}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Interface}/>
                    <Redirect path="/join/:id" to="/"/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Route` to match the `:id` parameter and pass it along in the location state:

```
<Route exact path='/join/:id' render={({match}) =>
     <Redirect to={{pathname: "/", state: {id: match.params.id}}}/>}
/>
```

In `Interface`, you can then access the id with `props.location.state.id`.